# SwiftUI: How to prevent view from dismissing after updating the array

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am making app where I have to be able to modify/delete data. I am using firebase so the original structure is more complex, but to show my problem I created test views. I am having hard time debugging issue with view dismissing itself. After deleting one item of nested array, it's dismissing my view, and I am not sure how to prevent that.

This is my model:

```
struct Object: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var nestedObjects: [NestedObject]
}
struct NestedObject: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
}
```

This is my View Model:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var objects = [
        Object(name: "1", nestedObjects: [
            NestedObject(name: "1.1"),
            NestedObject(name: "1.2"),
            NestedObject(name: "1.3"),
            NestedObject(name: "1.4"),
        ]),
        Object(name: "2", nestedObjects: [
            NestedObject(name: "2.1"),
            NestedObject(name: "2.2"),
            NestedObject(name: "2.3"),
            NestedObject(name: "2.4"),
        ])
    ]
}
```

Content View:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(vm.objects){ object in
                NavigationLink {
                    SubView(object: object)
                } label: {
                    Text(object.name)
                }

            }
        }.environmentObject(vm)

    }
}
```

And Nested View:

```
struct SubView: View {
    let object: Object
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        List(object.nestedObjects) { nested in
            HStack {
                Text(nested.name)
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    let array = object.nestedObjects.filter({$0.id != nested.id})
                    vm.objects = vm.objects.filter({$0.id != object.id})
                    vm.objects.append(Object(name: object.name, nestedObjects: array))
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "trash.fill")
                }.buttonStyle(.borderless)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I really want the structure to stay because I know that I am overdoing here in this example but in main project I have Firestone listener and after reaching which object is modified I have to change him, and that's when it's being dismissed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is happening because `NavigationLink` depends on the `Object` `id`. When you create a new `Object` by doing `Object(name: object.name, nestedObjects: array)`, it has a *new* and *different* `id` because of your definition of `id`: `var id = UUID()`

One solution would be to make a copy of the `Object`, replace the nested values, and then `map` it back into the original array.

Note that this might be even easier if you chose to structure your `Objects in a` Dictionary`keyed by`id` rather than an array, but that's certainly optional.

```
struct SubView: View {
    let object: Object
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        List(object.nestedObjects) { nested in
            HStack {
                Text(nested.name)
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    var copy = object
                    copy.nestedObjects = object.nestedObjects.filter { $0.id != nested.id }
                    vm.objects = vm.objects.map { $0.id == copy.id ? copy : $0 }
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "trash.fill")
                }.buttonStyle(.borderless)

            }
        }
    }
}
```